# ExtJs: how to disable fieldset on button click event

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, fieldset

I have a `fieldset` defined on my page. Now I want to enable or disable this field set on button click event. But it is not working properly. Below is the code I have written:

**To Disable**:

```
this.mySettings.query('[name="fieldsetName"]').forEach(function (field) {
    field.disable();
});
```

**To Enable:**

```
this.mySettings.query('[name="fieldsetName"]').forEach(function (field) {
    field.enable();
});
```

- **Issue-1** : When I disable fieldset, it seems to be disabled visually. But still I can access controls inside it.
- **Issue-2** : Once it is disabled, I cannot re-enable it.

I need a working sample with these two issues resolved.

Currently I am using `version 4.2` of `ExtJs`

Comment: What are the varieties of fields in the fieldset? Are you able to provide a fiddle?

Comment: @Jaimee: There are two checkboxes and one combobox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call the `setDisabled` function on the fieldset. It will disable all containing components.

```
fieldset.setDisabled(true);
// the fieldset and all inner components are disabled

fieldset.setDisabled(false);
// the fieldset and all inner components are enabled
```

[See the Sencha ExtJs 4.2.0 documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.FieldSet-method-setDisabled) and 
[the following minimal working example can be found on Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1t5a).

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',{
    items: [{
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        itemId: 'fieldsetId',
        items: [{
                    xtype: 'checkbox',
                    fieldLabel: 'Check 1'
                },{
                    xtype: 'checkbox',
                    fieldLabel: 'Check 2'
                },{
                    fieldLabel: 'Combo 1',
                    xtype: 'combobox',
                    store: ['value1','value2','value3']
                }]
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Disable fieldset',
        handler: function (button) {
            var fieldset = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('panel > #fieldsetId')[0];
            var toggle = !fieldset.isDisabled();
            var text = (toggle ? 'Enable' : 'Disable') + ' fieldset';
            fieldset.setDisabled(toggle);
            button.setText(text);
        }
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Paste this into a [Sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/) and hit **Run**:

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Fiddle', 'Welcome to Sencha Fiddle!');

        Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
            height: '100%',
            width: '100%',
            autoShow:true,
            bodyPadding: 25,
            title:'win',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'checkbox',
                    fieldLabel: 'field1'
                },{
                    xtype: 'checkbox',
                    fieldLabel: 'field2'
                },{
                    fieldLabel: 'field3',
                    xtype: 'combo',
                    store: ['asdf','zzasdf','dfdf']
                }]
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Enable/Disable entire fieldset',
                handler: function(btn){
                    var fset = btn.up('window').down('fieldset');
                    fset.setDisabled(!fset.disabled);
                }
            }, {
                margin: '0 0 0 10',
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Enable/Disable each field in fieldset individually',
                handler: function(btn){
                    var fset = btn.up('window').down('fieldset');
                    fset.items.each(function(i){
                        i.setDisabled(!i.disabled);
                    });
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```